# Can’t edit driven number value, see graph editor for driver setup

Tags: animation, geometry-nodes

I’m trying to follow the tutorial [Blender Guru Blender 3.0 Floating Particles Tutorial (Donut part 12)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oA4maNXlIf0&ab_channel=BlenderGuru) but at around 8min mark I keep getting the error:

> `Can’t edit driven number value, see graph editor for driver setup.`

I realise there are others that have asked this question but I still keep getting this error.

I'm stuck in a section where I'm trying to get the value node to link with the frames of my scene using a plane, then selecting the plane, inside the geometry nodes editor.

He adds a value node then goes to the value node box and in the value node and he inputs `#frame` to link to frames of his scene and that seems to work for Blender Guru. For me it does not work, so when I try changing the value all I seem to be getting is the error `can’t edit driver number value`

I tried right clicking on the value box, in the value node in Geometry node layout and deleting driver and then re-type #frame but that doesn’t seem to fix it. I tried deleting the value node and putting in a new node that did not fix it.

I noticed in drivers area that when input `#frame` into the value box of the value node it does add something but the message is always `can’t edit driver number value`. Maybe my blend file is corrupt?

Does anyone know what is wrong? I kind of just want to finish the tutorial. Any help would be great.

[image]

Comment: @quellenform, "Scene Time" Node was the answer and with that I was able to complete the tutorial. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were you, I would use the `Scene Time` node (available from version 3.1). This provides the current frame directly as a value.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try entering "frame" instead of "#frame". Sometimes, there are slight changes between releases of the product and it may be that "#ref' is no longer valid in 3.2.... I may be wrong about this particular instance, but there are many videos based on older blender versions that become obsolete quickly, unfortunately.

You'll see the error message in the Driver Editor.   In fact the proper way to use the UI to edit this is to RMB-"Copy As new Driver":

[image]

followed by "Paste Driver" into the field:

[image]

You cannot do this with every field in the interface but most fields/properties allow for this type of UI editing.